# Переадресация в node js с сохранением метода запроса

Tags: node.js

Как мне сделать переадресацию так, чтобы метод запроса сохранялся.
Если использовать res.redirect, то метод запроса всегда становится GET. Но мне, к примеру, нужно, чтобы он оставался POST.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307